# How to add event/trigger to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on mock store webpage and want to count the amount of elements that were added to the cart.

When I drag item to "Add to cart" button it changes the class of button. I'm trying to count new button class by using .length like below but it doesn't work because my code loads once when the page is loaded.

```js
var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-state-highlight').length; 
var cart = document.getElementById('cart');
cart.textContent =  cartItems + " items";
```

How should I make it work real time and respond to class changes? I'm just a beginner and would appreciate all your help!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable1").draggable({
    revert: "valid"
  });
  $("#draggable2").draggable({
    revert: "valid"
  });
  $("#draggable3").draggable({
    revert: "valid"
  });
  $("#draggable4").draggable({
    revert: "valid"
  });
  $("#droppable1").droppable({
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("button.b1")
        .html("Added!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#cart">Cart <img src="images/bag.png" style="width:20%; height:auto;"></a>
<span><i class="shopping-cart"></i></span>
<ul>
  <li id="cart"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As a beginner, here's a tip: if you find yourserlf duplicating, be highly suspicious that there's probably a better way. All those 4 draggables can be merged into one, by using a multi-selector e.g. `#draggable1, #draggable2, ...` etc.

Comment: @Utkanos you mean by adding a class and only having one line `$(".draggable").draggable(..`

Comment: Well you could do that, yes, or, like I said, simply pass multiple IDs to one selector.

Comment: @Utkanos thanks for the tip, will definitely use that!